# Can returning from a function in a SyncLock cause a deadlock?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, locking

Will a `SyncLock` in a function cause a deadlock if the function returns while the lock is in effect?

Consider the following example:

```
Dim LockObject As New Object

Public Function Myfunction() As Boolean    
   SyncLock LockObject     
      Return True    
   End SyncLock
End Function
```

Will the `End SyncLock` occur after the `return True`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does return inside a lock makes any difference?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268755/does-return-inside-a-lock-makes-any-difference)

Comment: If it could, what use would the synclock statement be? You wouldn't need it and could just write Monitor.Enter/Exit.